# Nuxtjs bad routing in Netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a NuxtJs (vue) application in Netlify, when I redirect to other pages, It will to concat the last page and the next.

For example:

https://page-example/register

I'm in this page, then I redirect to the next page with

```js
this.$router.push("confirmationsend");
```

In local I get this url :

> https://localhost:3001/confirmationsend

but in Netlify I get this url:

> https://page-example/register/confirmationsend

And NuxtJs can't resolve this routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either be pushing a path, like this

```js
this.$router.push('/confirmationsend')
// equivalent to this.$router.push({ path: '/confirmationsend' })
```

or use the `name` property (you can find the name in either your router file if you got one or in the Vue devtools)

```js
$router.push({ name: 'confirmationsend' })
```

As shown in [the Vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location).
Mixing both (name + path) is usually not a good idea since a push without a `/` is by default meaning "append it to my current route" in the context of a History push.

Hence why I do recommend any of the snippets above to be more explicit regarding what you're trying to tell to the Vue router/various hosting platforms.